# Unable to connect to Oracle database from SQL Developer

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a connection string in my web.config that is a normal one, as the connection strings that we have for sql database but this one is for oracle database that is found on a server on our network.

I think i am filling some fields wrong, like the port(i dunno what it is), sid (same issue).

I am getting this error:

> listener refused the connection with the following error ora-12505

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A connection string for SQL Server is very different from a connection string for Oracle.  You might check [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) to get examples of properly formatted connection strings.  Good luck.

Comment: post your connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SID` is the name of the database instance. The error message indicates you've got it wrong.

**Edit** the default value for the port is 1521, for the SID is ORCL. Both parameters are configured in the [tnsnames.ora](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) file on the database server.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is 100% right i will give you an upvote and the correct answer in few minutes (i can't now)